# How do I creathe then apply function over certain columns of a tibble?

Tags: r, function, apply, tidyverse

I am trying to practice R and learn more in general.  I would like to make a ratio of  x crime per 100,000 people.  The following is the head of my data. I decided to only use the 5 largest cities.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 13
City       Popula~ `Viol~ `Mur~ `Rap~ `Rap~ Robbe~ `Aggr~ `Prop~ Burgl~ `Larc~ `Moto~ Arson
 <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Abingdon      8186  10.0   0     3.00 NA      1.00   6.00  233    20.0  198    15.0   4.00
2 Alexandria  148519 258     5.00 21.0  NA    118    114    2967   249    2427   291    13.0 
3 Altavista     3486   8.00  0     0    NA      2.00   6.00   56.0   4.00   52.0   0     0   
4 Amherst       2223   2.00  0     2.00 NA      0      0      27.0   6.00   19.0   2.00  0   
5 Appalachia    1728  12.0   0     2.00 NA      2.00   8.00   77.0  25.0    51.0   1.00  0   
6 Ashland       7310  26.0   0     1.00 NA      8.00  17.0   246    14.0   221    11.0   1.00
```

The following code is my attempt.

```
virginia_crime %>%
 filter(Population > 180000) %>%
 group_by(City) %>%
 summarise(ratio_violent = `Violent
 crime`/(Population/100000),
 ratio_murder = `Murder and
 nonnegligent
 manslaughter`/(Population/100000))
```

The output is:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
City           ratio_violent ratio_murder
<chr>                  <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Chesapeake               320         3.90
2 Newport News             439         8.28
3 Norfolk                  573        11.3 
4 Richmond                 624        17.4 
5 Virginia Beach           162         3.77
```

I realize that I should be able to make a function that essentially creates a rate. Something like... rate <- (crime columns/(Population/1000).  Am I even close in my idea, or should I be using one of the apply functions (sapply(summarise()))? I feel this task could be automated somehow, I just cannot figure it out. Would appreciate some insight

Comment: You create a function and then use `summarise_at` or `summarise_if` though it is not clear about the expected output and the columns you want to summarise

Comment: @akrun I want to summarize all of the columns that are crimes, I believe, `[ ,3:13]`.  I am not sure how to create the function...

Comment: In that case use `%>% summarise_at(3:13, funs(yourfun))`.  Could you please update your post with the `dput` of the first 6 rows

Comment: `rate <- function(x){
  x/virginia_crime$Population/100000
}` I am not sure if this is correct... `virginia_crime %>%
  filter(Population > 180000) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  summarise_at(3:1, rate)`.. It did not work `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : `Column `Murder and
nonnegligent
manslaughter` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 149`

Comment: There is no need for `summarise` as you are not summarising anything, but modifying the columns with the ratio.  Please check if the solution  posted works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can gather your columns (all besides city and population) first, which lets you operate on all of them at once:

```
library(tidyr)

crime_rates <- virginia_crime %>%
  filter(Population > 180000) %>%
  gather(Crime, Number, -City, -Population) %>%
  mutate(Rate = Number / (Population / 100000))
```

This will end up with one row for each pair of city and crime, alongside the population, number, and rate.

If you want to turn it back into a wide form, you can use spread (after removing the `Number` column):

```
crime_rates %>%
  select(-Number) %>%
  spread(Crime, Rate)
```

---

It's worth noting that the gathered (tidied) version is still quite useful, for example if you want to find the cities with the highest rates of each crime (perhaps to use in a graph):

```
crime_rates %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  top_n(1, Rate)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is probably more similar to what we probably would have done in class. Is there a way to identify when it might be useful to use `gather()`? I found it difficult to visualize that function in my head when I learned it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `mutate_at`.  In the OP's code, `summarise` is used, but it is to summarise an object with 'n' rows to a single row.  The ratio always will be not be a single row (based on the OP's code and `mutate` should be used in place of `summarise`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(Population > 180000) %>% 
   mutate_at(3:13, funs(./Population/100000))
```